# verifying contents of a response: is that a controller test or an integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, integration-testing

Assume I have a list of named widgets.  Somewhere in my test code, I want to verify that

```
widget = FactoryGirl.create(:widget)
get :index
```

generates a page that contains the string #{widget.name} somewhere on it.

My question: do I write this as a controller test or as an integration test?

*(Aside #1: This seems outside the scope of a controller test, since it is assuming knowledge about what view is rendered.  But writing it as an integration test feels too heavyweight, since it only requires a single request / response transaction.)*

*(Aside #2, my general question is "how do you decide what goes in controller tests and what goes in integration tests?"  But this is arguably too broad for a Stack Overflow question.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sometimes I think Stack Overflow should award an RTFM badge, and that I should be one of the first to receive it!*

Digging around more, I found that RSpec supports "View specs" that are designed specifically to test the contents of what's rendered -- that's precisely what my original question was about.

The tests get written in spec/views/.  [Documentation and examples can be found here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec), but be sure to look at the documentation for your current version of RSpec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any universally agreed-upon definition for these different categories of test, but personally I would call this a "request spec", a kind of integration test but one that involves only a single request/response cycle. It is clearly more than a controller test because it involves all elements of the MVC architecture. On the other hand, you're not clicking around and then finding buttons, clicking them etc. so it's not what I would typically think of as an "integration test".

One simple way to distinguish between what I would call "request specs" and what you typically would call "integration tests" is the use of [`get`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get) (from ActionDispatch) vs [`visit`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#visit-instance_method) (from capybara). If you're only using `get` (and `post` etc.) then it is a request spec. If you're using `visit` then it's an integration test.

For more on the distinction between `get` and `visit`, see this post: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/ In that post there is a suggestion to get rid of spec/requests altogether and replace it by spec/api (for what I would call 'request specs') and spec/features (for what I would call 'integration tests').

Anyway note that what I've written above is just my own personal way of seeing this distinction, others may disagree.

Comment: I apologize if my question wasn't clear: In the RSpec world, request specs and integration tests are really the same thing.  In fact, you can use the Rails `get` or Capybara's `visit` interchangeably (though not within a single test), as per https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs.  Rather, I'm asking about controller vs [request | integration] tests.

Comment: `get` and `visit` are not interchangeable, at least in the sense that you can't just replace a `get` here by `visit` there or vice versa and expect the test to work. (Try using `fill_in` after making a `get` request.) Although I agree that both are really integration tests, there is an important distinction to be made -- and as the post I linked to explains, that distinction has caused confusion.

Comment: I agree completely with what you say -- in fact, I was the author of https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/527, so I'm keenly aware of the confusion between Rails calls and Capybara calls.  But that's not what my original question was about! :)

Comment: Ah ok I see :) Sorry about that. I guess for me, the answer would be yes this is something for an integration test and not a controller test, but the problem is that the "integration test" category is too large and covers too much territory, and maybe could use more fine-grain distinctions -- hence my suggestion. Re: your answer, I used to write view tests but just found them a kind of time sink. But now that I think about it, that is the correct answer to your question!